# Yugabyte Query Pattern / Tracing in YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Does Yugabyte has any tools that can observes the query’s pattern?
Or record statement being executed?
I.E. tracing in Cassandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an auditing feature that can show you queries in logs: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/secure/audit-logging/audit-logging-ycql/

There is a utility called `ybtop`, which allows you to display currently active queries too: https://github.com/fritshoogland-yugabyte/ybtop

Please note that `ybtop` shows queries whilst they are active, it does not record.